# How to get the current installation within the cloud function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

This was asked [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-access-a-user-installation-from-the-cloud) but without a clear answer on how to get the current installation from the cloud.

In my cloud function, I need to bind the current user with the current installation, I can send the current user within the request object to the cloud function, but I cannot find any way to get the current installation within the cloud code. I know this is pretty easy in iOS SDK but since I am using javascript, I need a way to access the current installation from the cloud code. How is that be doable?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the installationId from your current session.

```
Parse.Session.current()
  .then(function(session) {
    // Get the installation ID
    installationId = session.get('installationId');
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

edit: JavaScript doesn't have installations, so what installation are you trying to alter?

The answer is going to be the same here..  The "installation" isn't sent with every request like the user is, so you need to assign that relationship elsewhere.  Either you send in the current installation object id with your function request, or you save a pointer (either way) to pair the user and the installation together and then query for the related object in cloud code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, actually for the first way you suggested, how is it possible to send in the current installation object id with the function request? I just spent two hours on the cloud docs and didn't came with a way to do so, so it would be really kind of you to clarify that. As for the second way, I read many replies on parse forums about binding the current installation with the current user pointer, but the problem is that the installation row is created before the user object is created,so at the user object creation,how can I know which installation row was made for my device

Comment: What platform for the installation?.. for iOS it's [PFInstallation currentInstallation];, which you can save on the PFUser.. similar examples exist for the other platforms.

Comment: I am developing a phonegap app, so I cannot rely on iOS for the current installation because this cannot be dispatched over to the js code from native ios. I really need a js way.

Comment: how is the installation being created?

Comment: The installation object is being created automatically once the app launch. I am not doing so explicitly, so this is done automatically.

Comment: take a look here:  http://wait4ideas.wordpress.com/2014/04/29/push-notification-using-parse-js-sdk-and-phonegap/

Comment: @Fosco I'm using Parse javascript sdk to build ios and android application. I want the current installationId in app platform. Can you help me? what will be the code snippet to find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current installation from which the request is made like this:

```
// Get current installation
const currentInstallationId = request.installationId;
```